# Magento2 - How to move cart total below the cart items on checkout page?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I want to show the `cart totals` section below the `cart items` on the `checkout page`.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override your **checkout_index_index.xml** file and paste the below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">99</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Clean cache and check the output.

Hope it'll helpful for you.

Comment: I will check and update you. thanks!

Comment: It is working. Thanks!

Comment: Happy coding !! :)

Comment: Also, I want to add a coupon code section in the order summary. Please let me know.

Comment: okay. will update you soon.

Comment: Ok, Order summary coupon code, cart-items then cart-total.

Comment: Any update? @rohan

Comment: Did you get my answer? About coupon code.

Comment: Not yet.........

Comment: Ok, Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend the

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

in to your theme like

> app/design/frontend/[Theme_Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

And add the below code.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">100</item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Flush the cache and check, It works for me, Check the below screenshot.

[image]